How to convert Postfix email log mail to proper html content to show in web view
Below is the Postfix log for a received email. I want to render this content in my application, but I seem unable to do so.
When I use the content with the header: Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" it does not render a fully functional HTML page with proper styling and links.
On the other hand, if I use the content with the header: Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable, it renders with incorrect HTML tags and content, such as =>, 3D, and it also includes wrong HTML tags. I attempted to manually replace these using string manipulation, but this is not a viable solution for handling multiple types of emails.
From abcAbc@gmail.com  Fri Oct 11 18:53:02 2024
Return-Path: <abcAbc@gmail.com>
X-Original-To: w123@cosyhome.cloud
Delivered-To: root@cosyhome.cloud
Received: from mail-ej1-f47.google.com (mail-ej1-f47.google.com [209.85.218.47])
        by cosyhome.cloud (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 7A1A440011
        for <w123@cosyhome.cloud>; Fri, 11 Oct 2024 18:53:02 +0000 (UTC)
Received: by mail-ej1-f47.google.com with SMTP id a640c23a62f3a-a99c0c203f0so116440266b.2
        for <w123@cosyhome.cloud>; Fri, 11 Oct 2024 11:53:02 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20230601; t=1728672779; x=1729277579; darn=cosyhome.cloud;
        h=to:subject:message-id:date:from:mime-version:from:to:cc:subject
         :date:message-id:reply-to;
        bh=oQaO5RO6Ym5PMYtEFtzdpKgrGUmnUwSkiyXGFtVu/Xg=;
        b=QfDMySSFVtZOw7R/vSSXWx/jt/g1j1+n4tDDdsRLIbhLX8/9nd2L4i3axXgj8Wp8Gy
         gZsPfwkh7wThYT2JZawU9WB7VLficDNgJvc1tfihVYrsLKMydA8gblm5cp+dJ3FWaGiQ
         04wbvHG+y6nofBVLEnkLM1u12zFiaMLyorwxb5Cj+wUXra/kbEAh7DhDwKlUqppoVHHV
         uRqW8IS3FzelDLdXbrk8TqlmveTW1/uohMrhBhFv/VtAEcMXLXw3CEIY1n8jhIbOGYJv
         Rny/dp6+oaUGOI7kfe3+Fiy0lh6VnXhAK4FxKbns9ctIe6kCdFIeG/PduRycawyNo15H
         lD4A==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20230601; t=1728672779; x=1729277579;
        h=to:subject:message-id:date:from:mime-version:x-gm-message-state
         :from:to:cc:subject:date:message-id:reply-to;
        bh=oQaO5RO6Ym5PMYtEFtzdpKgrGUmnUwSkiyXGFtVu/Xg=;
        b=iszP8pqB6F/LVrGCFAabjHDagGgi6sdb/106fSUvuxDSYa9luAXkxTxoPMYjdTUix1
         /J9ZFA9OICjGXkyE+CLXIxwdgTAdLUq9j3BRKgqKowWzOe6ZJayF0sE47o+wRQuwnxQh
         9VhLve18rAIrj+xd8/p6LthoiBuEvzgIENcmHeV5po0o1oPKPe2Zs0q+XcnDTo0Us9EW
         sDpK2s/lDiR9PYygwDspOf4tc/kk79rmO4idhwRUJH7UoJ5t0aXx0dGQI7KrwhGU74R6
         C6V11AEv4EAm5txkE/6CKUDYXFmbPjPgiJgZ40PAhymvcx4LVQZKQmwwh3WauD1LUI/n
         JGPA==
X-Gm-Message-State: AOJu0Yw8v83eWmLvQptFNjIO+AenK8gZs+RtRlZ5qv3nugVW0qM+BDSB
        mai/kMQEu1dhQ+p/5TNvxQInCzGCSKMtX+FyFhApxIKJb5RwK/4GksCT/v8MpWM3Hu61sQ3q2Zy
        Rew16AdofHlyUmEafaVoxZXVlD9htY3GDMZI=
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IFfHQouTWujRz/MYsx0bMfPOJTTJeSu7XEHADhZQMygD9HeP+Q0AGJNoa85g6/ggVMVNsDUQYQS2dggcY+/5t0=
X-Received: by 2002:a17:907:e614:b0:a99:446f:4c1 with SMTP id
 a640c23a62f3a-a99e3cf8061mr46754366b.33.1728672779204; Fri, 11 Oct 2024
 11:52:59 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Abc Cde Abewicrama <abcAbc@gmail.com>
Date: Sat, 12 Oct 2024 02:52:48 +0800
Message-ID: <CAOzeRSXT35-xfHijtJNT0tq7qEnfRAu358JPqN9npo64PH221w@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: w
To: w123@cosyhome.cloud
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000f005c0062437fed6"

--000000000000f005c0062437fed6
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

sdds


Best Regards,
Abc Cde
Linkedin <https://lk.linkedin.com/in/Abc-Cde-abeywickrama-7a8379a9>
 | Github <https://github.com/abcAbc>

--000000000000f005c0062437fed6
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir=3D"ltr">sdds<br clear=3D"all"><div><div dir=3D"ltr" class=3D"gmail=
_signature" data-smartmail=3D"gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div d=
ir=3D"ltr"><div><div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div style=3D"font-size:s=
mall;font-family:&quot;trebuchet ms&quot;,sans-serif;color:rgb(0,0,0)"><br>=
</div><div style=3D"font-size:small;font-family:&quot;trebuchet ms&quot;,sa=
ns-serif;color:rgb(0,0,0)"><br></div><div style=3D"font-size:small;font-fam=
ily:&quot;trebuchet ms&quot;,sans-serif;color:rgb(0,0,0)">Best Regards,</di=
v><div style=3D"font-size:small;font-family:&quot;trebuchet ms&quot;,sans-s=
erif;color:rgb(0,0,0)">Abc Cde</div><div style=3D"font-size:small;f=
ont-family:&quot;trebuchet ms&quot;,sans-serif;color:rgb(0,0,0)"><a href=3D=
"https://lk.linkedin.com/in/Abc-Cde-abeywickrama-7a8379a9" style=3D=
"color:rgb(17,85,204)" target=3D"_blank">Linkedin</a>=C2=A0|=C2=A0<a href=
=3D"https://github.com/abcAbc" target=3D"_blank"><font face=3D"Aria=
l, Helvetica, sans-serif">G</font>ithub</a>=C2=A0</div></div></div></div></=
div></div></div></div></div></div>

--000000000000f005c0062437fed6--

Does anyone have any ideas or proper methods to render this content?
Below is the relevant log file related to inbox emails.

Emails are encoded, usually in sections. Each section can have a different encoding. This means you need to detect the sections and decode them. For a quoted-printable see: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html
